# RecyclerView giving Null Object Reference when used with MaterialNavigationDrawer Library

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use [MaterialNavigationDrawer](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer) library. The wiki says:

MaterialNavigationDrawer is an ActionBarActivity, but there are some important changes:

- you have an init method
- you must not override onCreate method
- you must not call setContentView method, because the library have it's own layout
- you must not override onBackPressed method, because the library implement it on its own

So I used this code and removed the onCreate method code. I put the RecyclerView initialization code inside the init function (which I was earlier doing in onCreate).

```
public class MainActivity extends MaterialNavigationDrawer implements
        OffersFragment.OnEnterNameFragmentInteractionListener,
        OfferDetailsFragment.OnShowNamesFragmentInteractionListener {

    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    public void init(Bundle bundle) {
        loadSampleData();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_offers);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        RecyclerViewAdapter rvAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, offerList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);


        MaterialAccount account = new MaterialAccount(this.getResources(),
                "Akshay","akshay.thapa23@gmail.com",R.drawable.photo, R.drawable.navbar_header);
        account.setTitle("Title");
        this.addAccount(account);

        MaterialSection section = newSection("Share", R.drawable.ic_share_grey600_24dp, new OffersFragment());
        this.addSection(section);

        MaterialSection settingsSection = newSection("Settings", new OffersFragment());
        this.addBottomSection(settingsSection);
    }
....
....
}
```

But this is giving me the below error,  I guess thats not how I'm supposed to do it. Can anyone please help?

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' **on a null object reference**
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it work by referencing [this](https://github.com/tongcpp/RecyclerView-Sample/blob/master/src/com/example/recyclerview/RecyclerFragment.java). Instead of intializing the recycler view inside the parent activity, I now do it in the Fragment itself and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using just activity context `linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);`